# Are items with +0AC are only aesthetic or do they bring some defense or other benefits?

Tags: temple-of-elemental-evil

I am finding items with +0 AC all over the place, also my starting characters have them

[image]

[image]

Since they have +0AC it would imply that in fights they don't add any protection, they do weight more than zero however so discarding them would allow me to carry more loot.

**Are items with +0AC are only aesthetic or do they bring some defense or other benefits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just cosmetic.

It's common for new characters in RPGs like these to start out with basic clothing, which doesn't have any real effect in the game besides looks.

Any stats on the item will be displayed (as long as the item is identified). So, if you want to save a bit of weight and don't mnid oyur characters running around naked, sure, you can throw it away.

Keep in mind though, especially wizards won't get items with stats very quickly, as they don't wear normal armor, only magical robes.

Comment: A slight flaw in game design IMHO, toee is filled with traders selling chainmail gloves and boots with +0AP for 20+ gold that are as good as nothing, lol

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Not everythnig in a role-playing game must have some gameplay effect. I wouldn't call cosmetic items a flaw in game design, some people may want their character look like completely clad in chainmail and it'll be a while before you find magical gloves, which have a gameplay effect.